# CreateGooglePhotorealistic3DTileset with sunlight

Tags: cesiumjs

I’m using CreateGooglePhotorealistic3DTileset . Following the recommendations, I set viewer.scene.globe.show = false . However, I would like to utilize the sunlight. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

I tried setting viewer.scene.globe.show = true, but I some areas, the map didnt work well